# Button click submits the form only on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

This Meteor client code has 2 buttons, the "CLEAR" button suppose to clear the input box, the following behaviour was noticed:

1) Firefox browsers; 52.2.1 on windowsXP and 54.1 on mac, does not clear input box but instead, it invokes the `clickInfo()`.

2) Works fine on the following browsers:
   a) Chrome 59 on mac
   b) Safari 10.2
   c) Chrome on Android

The code needs to be able to invoke the `clickInfo()` either by clicking/tapping on the INFO button or by hitting the ENTER key on the key board.

Any idea how to get the CLEAR button to clear the input box on all browsers? thx

```
Template.footer.events({
  'click #clear': () => {
    event.preventDefault();
    dict.set('busy', false);
    dict.set('prop1', '');
    let elem = document.getElementById('prop1');
    elem.value = '';
    elem.focus();
  },
  'click #info': function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    clickInfo();
  }
});
Template.body.events({
  'submit form': function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    clickInfo();
  }
});
```

```html
<head>
  <title>myTitle</title>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/appIcon.png"/>
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/appIcon.png"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  {{> header}}
  <div id="main">
    <div id="login-div">{{> loginButtons align='right'}}</div>
    <div id="content">
      <form>
        <button type="submit" style="display:none"></button>
        {{> content}}
        {{> footer}}
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

<template name="footer">
  <footer>
    <button id="clear">CLEAR</button>
    <button id="info">INFO</button>
  </footer>
</template>
```

Comment: `event.preventDefault();` ... global `event` object is an old internet exploder hack ... which chrome has taken on board for some stupid reason ,,, use `(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();` for proper browsers - if you check the browser developer tools console, you should see an error with your code (debugging 101)

Comment: thx. that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this `'submit form': function (e) {`,

use **e** instead of **event**